# Dialog Fragment and RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, dialog, dialogfragment

I'm trying to make an RecycleView DialogFragment on EditText Click, but i have some problem with that: I can't implement Recycler.
I have something like that:

[image]

DialogFragment class:

```
public class PatientDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, null));
        builder.setTitle("Choose Patient");
        builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, container, false);

        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPatientsDialog);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final PatientsAdapter adapter = new PatientsAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        return root;
    }
}
```

Dialog xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewPatientsDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:listitem="@layout/person_item"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and main fragment editText listener:

```
        editTextPatient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final PatientDialogFragment patientDialogFragment= new PatientDialogFragment();
                patientDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "myTag");
            }
        });
```

I bet that there is some problem with DialogFragment class, but don't know what exactly.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you inflating your view twice? remove your inflate inside onCreateDialog and move codes inside onCreateView. inside onCreateView inflate and return your view, override onViewCreated and inside it setup your views (like onClickListeners, texts, adapters and etc)

Comment: and set your recyclerView to match_parent

Comment: Hmm, i make something like this, but still don't work: https://pastebin.com/raw/439K6XZw

Comment: like this: https://pastebin.com/E7Ga4Swj

Comment: Now, I don't even see a dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you should put all code in `onCreateDialog` method, like this.

```
public class PatientDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Context context = requireActivity();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, null);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPatientsDialog);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        PatientsAdapter adapter = new PatientsAdapter();

        // Create patient list here to pass into PatientsAdapter
        // This demo I just create some random patients, replace on your own version.
        List<Patient> patientList = new ArrayList<>();
        patientList.add(new Patient("Alice", "Liddel", System.currentTimeMillis(), "note"));
        patientList.add(new Patient("Bob", "Martin", System.currentTimeMillis(), "note2"));
        patientList.add(new Patient("Clark", "Ken", System.currentTimeMillis(), "note3"));
        adapter.setPatients(patientList);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(dialogView)
                .setTitle("Choose Patient")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

**Update:** Your dialog is still empty because you do not set any data (patients) for your `PatientsAdapter` yet, please see my code above for more information.

Comment: I have an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. Where should I call removeView()?

Comment: Ok, I have put that before return:         ((ViewGroup)recyclerView.getParent()).removeView(recyclerView); I don't have exception, but I don't have RecyclerView in dialog either.

Comment: @domvnski can you post stacktrace when you get the exception?

Comment: I don't know, but I can't get this exception right now. Here is my all project: https://ufile.io/gn25u76q can you look at it?

Comment: @domvnski good to hear that, btw if your problem has been solved, then you can mark at least one answer as accepted.